# Please help identify, could be a Bionicle? (yellow with green mask)

Tags: set-identification, bionicle

Pieces could have come from disassembling a Bionicle.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a portion of [8998-1 Toa Mata Nui](https://brickset.com/sets/8998-1/Toa-Mata-Nui).

[image: Set picture]

This set is sometimes called "Titan Mata Nui" among fans, to better distinguish this "Titan" set from the regular "[Mata Nui](https://brickset.com/sets/8989-1/Mata-Nui)" set, which is how the character Toa Mata Nui actually appears in BIONICLE media.

The transparent green piece does not go to it though, and I'm not sure what it is.